# Android AlertDialog how can I identify item which launched dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I want to have a menu on second activity for application settings so I used ListView. Now I want to put some information to table based on the clicked item i.e. if phone item was clicked I want to open some dialog to enter phone number but if email item was clicked I want open a dialog but with different data so I have to know which item was clicked. Here is how it looks now:

```
mainListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {
            String item = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();
            showInputDialog();
        }
    });

public void showInputDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert.setTitle("Phone number");
    alert.getContext().
    // Set an EditText view to get user input
    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
    alert.setView(input);


    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            dataEntry = input.getText().toString();
            settingsList.put("phone",dataEntry);
            fileManage.writeFile(file, settingsList);
            fileManage.readFile(file);
        }
    });

    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            // Canceled.
        }
    });

    alert.show();
}
```

Comment: OMG it was so obvious, there is an (long id) in setOnItemClickListener so now it goes like this:

            mainListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                    long id) {
                String item = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();
                showInputDialog(id);
            }
        });

public void showInputDialog(long id) {}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you pass the clicked item to the showInputDialog() method.

```
public void showInputDialog(String item){}
```

And in the onItemClick method:

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                            long id) {
        String item = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();
        showInputDialog(item);
    }
```

so you can identify by clicking which item was your dialog lunched.